# Unable to perform google sheet operation using API

Tags: google-api, google-sheets-api, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I am facing a problem in deleting and inserting records in the Google sheet using Google Sheet API. Please find the error below.

Delete Range: Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError

Internal error encountered.
[500]

Errors
[

```
Message[Internal error encountered.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
```

]

I am using Gsuite API in the UIPATH an RPA tool.

Where I am able to read the Data from the sheet but unable to Delete and Insert. I am sure that this problem is not on Uipath Side but the API side.

Please help

Comment: Can you show what scopes are you using? Either you are missing the appropriate write scopes, or you are using an account that does not have write access to this spreadsheet. Also, can you show the code related to the request?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @lamblichus In Uipath there is Gsuite Application scope, To delete there is Delete Range activity which probably calls the delete API

Comment: Is there any code you're using?

Comment: Actually, I am using Activities design by Uipath. I am just providing the Spreedsheet ID, sheet Name, values which I want to insert, and cell reference The code is wrapped inside that activity which I don't have access to...

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your XAML workflow, and perhaps a screenshot of the error message you are receiving? From the sounds of the error `Internal error encountered. [500]` it would suggest that the issue is with the API/Activities rather than an issue with the code/workflow you've created